# Building an infinite stream in dr.Racket overloads my memory limit?

Tags: stream, racket

For an Assignment im building my own Stream Implementation in Dr.Racket, i think i have it all done correctly...

however now im trying to implicitly define some infinite streams to work with for testing everything

```
(define ones (stream-cons 1 ones))
```

-i have created my own implementation of cons-stream, and i don't believe that is the issue here the issue is when i try and run this code i get an error saying

```
ones: undefined;
reference an identifier before its definition
```

what am i doing wrong? if i was to say create a procedure like

```
(define (ones) (stream-cons 1 ones))
```

i am the definition is allowed but the implementation would need to change a little

Comment: The most likely cause of this is your `stream-cons` macro. Can you post the code for it?

Comment: Your error is probably in your stream-cons macro or that you have implemented is as a procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct call to ones is `(stream-first ones)`.

See the Racket documentation: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html